# SyndicationFeed Class doesn't handle RSS version 0.91

Tags: syndication-feed

The SyndicationFeed Class in .NET only seems to support RSS version 2.0. How do I go about supporting RSS version 0.91?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you need to create a class that handles the serialization and deserialization of the RSS 0.91 standard. Such a class should derive from the SyndicationFeedFormatter class.

I've created such a class and provide its source code and a description of how to use it here:
[Syndicating and Consuming RSS 1.0 (RDF) Feeds in ASP.NET 3.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140320/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031809-1.aspx).

Happy programming!

Comment: Scott, thanks for your solution. It's working for me for RSS 1.0, but when I try to consume RSS 0.91 from http://www.bitwisemag.com/2/backend.php I get the error: "Unknown RSS 1.0 feed format."

Comment: You'll need to take his code and write a similar bit to cope with version 0.91. I had to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the **CodeHollow.FeedReader** package which supports multiple RSS versions (including 0.91): https://github.com/codehollow/FeedReader