# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rss

Additional information: The Rss20Serializer does not support RSS version '0.91'.

I'm trying to create an RSS Reader for WP7 in Visual Studio 2010 and I have it working using the SyndicationServices. I have it working with most RSS feeds but for some it just crashes the application, presenting me with the "unhandled exception" error.

Any idea why this may work flawlessly with some links but not with others?
I will post any code, if needed.

Example of RSS feed link working:

- http://rt.com/news/today/rss/

Example of RSS feed link **NOT** working:

- http://www.rte.ie/rss/news.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [SyndicationFeed Class doesn't handle RSS version 0.91](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925104/syndicationfeed-class-doesnt-handle-rss-version-0-91)

Comment: RSS was an ugly mess for a while.  Well, still is.

Answer (score 0):

Check each project in the solution - sometimes what you find when you see this issue is one of the projects in the solution have a **Target framework is mismatching** the others.

There are a handful of reasons this pops up but its usually due to something you are referencing either doesn't exist or has mismatching assemblies